# Trying to write code that includes a weather API

Tags: ruby

This is some code for a weather application I am building to be run at the command-line. I can not get it to run at all.

How would I implement this weather API to just give me feedback of weather in San Francisco?

```
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'

class Weather
  attr_accessor :weather
  def initialize
    weather = []
  end

  def play
    puts "Hi, this app is about to tell you the current weather in San Francisco! It is called CaliSunshine and is meant to bum you out about being so cold, would you like to proceed????? (Yes or No)"
    get_input 
  end

  if get_input == "yes"
    puts "#{temp_f}"
  elsif 
    puts "Too Bad! #{temp_f} dont you just wish you were in San Francisco?!"
  end
end 


def get_input
  print ">>>"
  user_input = gets
  user_input = user_input.strip
end

def SF_weather

  response_hash = JSON.load(RestClient.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/a68a17ccd80a1ab1/geolookup/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json')) 
  response_hash["current_observation"].each do |temp|
  end

end

Weather.new
```

Comment: It's not important to us whether you're a beginner or not, it's whether you ask a good question. Which you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put things in order:

```
require 'json'
require 'rest-client'

class Weather
  attr_accessor :weather

  def initialize
    weather = []
  end

  def play
    puts "Hi, this app is about to tell you the current weather in San Francisco! It is called CaliSunshine and is meant to bum you out about being so cold, would you like to proceed????? (Yes or No)"

    if get_input == "yes"
      puts "#{temp_f}"
    elsif
      puts "Too Bad! #{temp_f} dont you just wish you were in San Francisco?!"
    end
  end

  def get_input
    print ">>> "
    gets.chomp
  end

  def temp_f
    response_hash = JSON.parse(RestClient.get('http://api.wunderground.com/api/a68a17ccd80a1ab1/geolookup/conditions/q/CA/San_Francisco.json'))
    response_hash["current_observation"]["temp_f"]
  end
end

Weather.new.play
```